# msbuild GenerateDepsFile fails

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, nuget, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

All my projects are not failing to build on my Azure DevOps MacOS build host. It's a self-hosted build host. Suddenly, my projects are throwing this error when trying to build:

```
error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
error MSB4018: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageDependency> NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFileTargetLibrary.get_Dependencies()
```

I found this GitHub issue which seemed similar, but the posted solution didn't help me:
https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/13537

```
As mentioned in xamarin/xamarin-android#3155 this is caused by a version mismatch in nuget between msbuild and dotnet core. The solution is to update your dotnet core install to the latest stable version
```

I've installed the most recent .NET Core, and updated Visual Studio for Mac, but alas, the problem remains.

Another information:
When I build the same Xamarin.iOS project from my Windows machine coupled with the same MacOS build host, the app builds just fine. But I am guessing the process is probably different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating both Visual Studio for Mac and .NET Core SDK again today seems to have fixed the problem.